# I want to add a rounds div to the background

Tags: html, css, sass

border-radius failed to solve my problem.

I need to make a circular background for a region within the page as in the image.

My 1st question: it should only be the top of the page, not the bottom.

My 2nd question: how can I create such a circle?

Here's my code template:

HTML

```
<div className={styles.landing__page__4}>
      <div className={styles.ellipsis__background} />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.landing__page__4 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 60px;
  position: relative;
  .ellipsis__background {
    position: absolute;
    background: #19092e;
    box-shadow: 0px -5px 75px rgba(112, 0, 255, 0.82);
    border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    // bottom: -50%;
  }
```

thank you..

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by drawing the entire circle and giving it a height of 200vh (or whatever twice the height of the `.landing__page__4` container is). Then give the container an overflow of hidden:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.landing__page__4 {
  background: #19092e;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ellipsis__background {
  box-shadow: 0px -5px 75px rgba(112, 0, 255, 0.82);
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200vh;
  margin-top: 46px;
}
```

```html
<div class="landing__page__4">
  <div class="ellipsis__background"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to keep the circle in the upper part of the screen, while also respecting your `60px` top margin, you could constrain the circle's height to half of the viewport height (`50vh`) and add an `aspect-ratio` of `1` to ensure it remains a perfect circle at any viewport height.

```css
.landing__page__4 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 60px;
  position: relative;
}

 .ellipsis__background {
    position: absolute;
    background: #19092e;
    box-shadow: 0px -5px 75px rgba(112, 0, 255, 0.82);
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    aspect-ratio: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="landing__page__4">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium possimus deleniti incidunt provident quo maiores fugiat, ullam reprehenderit quasi alias expedita pariatur accusamus, atque delectus, eum dolores. Fugiat, voluptate, hic.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium possimus deleniti incidunt provident quo maiores fugiat, ullam reprehenderit quasi alias expedita pariatur accusamus, atque delectus, eum dolores. Fugiat, voluptate, hic.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium possimus deleniti incidunt provident quo maiores fugiat, ullam reprehenderit quasi alias expedita pariatur accusamus, atque delectus, eum dolores. Fugiat, voluptate, hic.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium possimus deleniti incidunt provident quo maiores fugiat, ullam reprehenderit quasi alias expedita pariatur accusamus, atque delectus, eum dolores. Fugiat, voluptate, hic.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium possimus deleniti incidunt provident quo maiores fugiat, ullam reprehenderit quasi alias expedita pariatur accusamus, atque delectus, eum dolores. Fugiat, voluptate, hic.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium possimus deleniti incidunt provident quo maiores fugiat, ullam reprehenderit quasi alias expedita pariatur accusamus, atque delectus, eum dolores. Fugiat, voluptate, hic.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium possimus deleniti incidunt provident quo maiores fugiat, ullam reprehenderit quasi alias expedita pariatur accusamus, atque delectus, eum dolores. Fugiat, voluptate, hic.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Praesentium possimus deleniti incidunt provident quo maiores fugiat, ullam reprehenderit quasi alias expedita pariatur accusamus, atque delectus, eum dolores. Fugiat, voluptate, hic.</p>    
  </div>
  <div class="ellipsis__background"></div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w1m34bjk/3/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to crop the bottom half from your ellipse then use clip path. To make it appear as a background use z-index of -1. To ensure it remains as a circle use aspect-ratio:1/1.

See example

```css
body {
  background-color: #19092e;
  color: white;
}
.ellipsis__container {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100vh;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:-1;
}
.ellipsis__background {
  background: #19092e;
  box-shadow: 0px -5px 75px rgba(112, 0, 255, 0.82);
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 50%, 0 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class='ellipsis__container'>
  <div class="ellipsis__background"></div>
</div>
Blah blah blah
```